# Some basic questions about $C^k(I \times A)$

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, continuity

Let $I=[0,T]$ and $A$ be a bounded set that may or may not be compact.

Let $f=f(x,t) \in C^k(I \times A)$. Am I right:

1) $f_x, f_t \in C^{k-1}(I \times A)$

2) $f_{xt}, f_{tx}, f_{xx}, f_{tt} \in C^{k-2}(I \times A)$

3) $f(x,\cdot) \in C^k(I)$ and $f(\cdot,t) \in C^k(A)$

Sorry for so easy question but I never learn about product spaces much. Are there any other obvious properties of such functions that I miss? also a reference to a book/lecture notes would be appreciated. Thanks